# Cors and why i am not able to send a request

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cors, cross-domain, react-context

```
import React,{useContext,useState} from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import {Context,server} from "../main.jsx";
import {Link,Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

const Register = () => {
    const [name,setName] = useState("");
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password,setPassword] = useState("");
    const {isAuthenticated,setIsAuthenticated,loading,setLoading} = useContext(Context);
    const submitHandler = async(e) => {
        setLoading(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const {data} = await axios.post(`${server}/users/new`,{name,email,password},{withCredentials:true,headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
            }});
            toast.success(data.message);
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        catch(error){
            toast.error(error.response.data.message);
            setLoading(false);
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }
    }
    if(isAuthenticated) 
        return <Navigate to={"/"}/>;
    else
        return (
        <div className="login">
            <section>
                <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                    <input value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Name" required/>
                    <input type="email" placeholder='Email' required value={email} onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                    <input type="password" onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} required placeholder='Password' value={password} />
                    <button type="submit">Signup</button>
                    <h4>Or</h4>
                    <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

I am trying to make a request to the backend from the frontend to submit the following form data and create the user.
However cors (browser) is blocking the request and i am getting the following error

ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/users/me' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

the way the request is begin sent i have already put above.

the backend is working  fine with postman i'll attach the way i have implemented the backend for cors

```
import express from "express";
import userRouter from "./routes/user.js";
import taskRouter from "./routes/task.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import {errorMiddleware} from "./middlewares/error.js";
import cors from "cors";

// Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header-based protocol that enables a server to dictate which origins can access its resources. Put another way, your server can specify which websites can tell a user's browser to talk to your server, and precisely which types of HTTP requests are allowed.

export const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'PRODUCTION') {
  dotenv.config({
    path: 'backend/config/config.env'
  })
}


//using middlewares 

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(cors({
    origin:[process.env.FRONTEND_URL],
    methods:["GET","POST","PUT","DELETE"],
    credentials:true
}))


//using routes
app.use("/api/v1/users",userRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/task",taskRouter);

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("Nicely Working");
})

// using error middleware 
app.use(errorMiddleware);
```

Can some one please tell me how should ifix this error and reason behind why this error is raised.
Thankyou for you time and efforts.

To understand the reason behind the error and the way I should fix this error.

Comment: Check if there is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response

Comment: What is the exact value of `process.env.FRONTEND_URL`?

Comment: the exact value of frontend_url is http://localhost:5000

Comment: @Konrad Should I apply another middleware to add the headers

Comment: @AdityaSharma So you're sending a request from `http://localhost:5173` but you're only allowing `http://localhost:5000` in your CORS config? That cannot work.